# Hugo taxonomy output name

Tags: hugo

I have a taxonomy layout `/layouts/talks/taxonomy.html` for web pages. I have enabled custom output, `calendar` and have a `/layouts/talks/taxonomy.ics` template for ICS files. It is rendered as: `/talks/talk-name/index.ics`.

Is there a way to rename a slug for the custom output file? I want to name it as `event.ics`.

Comment: Have you tried the https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#toml-front-matter ?

Comment: @Carles can't add front matter to non-md file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can change defaults:

```
[outputFormats]
[outputFormats.calendar]
  BaseName = "event"
```